# Format Exception - removal of time from DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, model-view-controller

I'm working in visual studio with MVC. My goal is to remove the time from the Date from in a column in my database called DTStamp. I was able to successfully modify my other fields with the same datatype of DateTime in the view like so:

@item.NoteDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

However DTStamp gives me an error in my model :

quotes1.DTStamp = DateTime.Parse(DT.Rows[i]["DTStamp"].ToString());

stating that the Format Exception was unhandled by usercode. String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

This might be because not all of the cells have values. Please help.

Comment: When you debug what is the value of `DT.Rows[i]["DTStamp"].ToString()`?

Comment: It shows me the dates i.e; (5/1/2017 2:35:44 PM}

Comment: However when it iterates over row 4456 it shows this: { }

Comment: Maybe look into [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: So `DTStamp` is nullable?

Comment: Yes it is, and I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

If it's because not all of the cells have values then maybe try [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
DateTime dateValue;

if(DateTime.TryParse(DT.Rows[i]["DTStamp"].ToString(), out dateValue)
{
   <td>@dateValue.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td>
}
else
{
    <td></td>
}
```

Maybe this will give you an idea.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(DT.Rows[i]["DTStamp"].ToString())) {
    quotes1.DTStamp= DateTime.Parse(DT.Rows[i]["DTStamp"].ToString());
}
```